# Importing multi-project SVN repository does not import all files created with svn copy

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

We're trying to move a legacy svn repository containing multiple projects into multiple git repositories.

Our repository setup is similar to this: https://daneomatic.com/2010/11/01/svn-to-multiple-git-repos/ , and following the suggestions in that post - while outdated - leads to properly split up repositories.

The actual process of splitting up the projects into different repositories is okay, but upon performing the svn repository import into git, several files and folders were not present after the import completed.

I tracked it down to files and folders where the svn log showed that they had been svn copied from other locations in the svn tree, and no matter what flags I experiment with when running `git svn clone` (such as specifying `trunk`, using `filter-branch` and similar) it seems like `git-svn` isn't able to resolve the svn cp, resulting in missing files and folders after the import has completed.

My theory is that the git svn import fails to "resolve" the svn copy. Even when doing a full import of the entire repository, the files in question are still missing, and comparing to a regular svn checkout I can pinpoint several missing files and folders.

Does anyone have any experience with this, flags I can use on `git svn`, or tool suggestions to complete an import like this? I'd like to complete the import keeping the history somewhat intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories like yours that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: I did look at the KDE svn2git tool, but the documentation seemed so tailored towards the KDE migration usecase that I wasn't sure it would even work. Your answer seems like it may actually be worth investigating further. I will report back when I've had a run with it.

Comment: I've managed to download the tool and run it successfully on the repository copy. It's blazingly fast - but as far as I can tell, it only creates the `.git` folder contents in the repository location I specify - what do I have to do to get the actual repository containing files? Am I missing a step?

Comment: It is absolutely generic, not tailored to KDE at all. Maybe you miss to checkout? It's been a while since I used it last. I'm not fully size whether it produces a bare repo that you then can clone or a non-bare where you have to checkout.

Comment: Turns out I needed to clone the folder after I ran the script. Unfortunately, `svn2git` exhibits the same problem as `git svn`, it's still missing the same set of files and folders. I'm going to try and experiment with the recipes, but the problem still stands :/

Comment: Then most likely your rules file is not matching your history. At this point I can probably only help if you share that repository. Everything else would be blind guessing.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out and pointing me in the right direction. It turned out the issue wasn't the `svn cp` history, but that some folders were mounted as local svn externals, which was a bit hard to detect. We still ended up using `svn2git` to do the import, saving us an enormous amount of time, so thanks for that.

Comment: You should have a look at the possible arguments. I think `--propcheck` should have warned about the externals. It warns about everything but `svn:ignore` which you can make it translate to `.gitignore` files.

Comment: If that other repo is in the same SVN root URL, you can modify your rules file to have it integrated in your result repo. If not, you could probably transform those external parts into separate repos and then use something like `git stitch-repo` or similar to combine the repos to one.